# How do I report a bug in a kernel if it won't boot?

Tags: kernel, bug-reporting

I have a problem on my machine with all of the kernels from:

- 2.6.38-8 (the default kernel in natty narwhal)
- Upto the present kernel in 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Basically the kernel wont boot meaning I can't use apport to collect data for the bug

[My hardware spec](http://paste.ubuntu.com/675315/)

Doing a verbose boot shows the boot hanging on this line

`ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.1: irq 16, io mem 0xfe02d000`

Having done a bit of research on the subject ohci is in relation to the USB bus

Any advice about how to report this on launchpad would be appreciated and any work around suggestions would be welcome

As far as I can tell replacing the kernel in the official image with an older or hacked newer one which I have no Idea how to do.

Comment: Every kernel version from somewhere between 2.6.35 and 2.6.38 (haven't managed to pin-point the exact version yet, haven't thried much either)  until the present-day version overheats my system as well. Something must have gone terribly wrong around that time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fantastic pages from The kernel Team:

Introduction : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam

Kernel Debugging : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging

- Debugging Scenarios
- Debugging Guides
- Debugging Tools/Information

Note : To determine which guides are relevant to your problem see the [Kernel/Debugging/Symptom](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Symptom) based debugging guide .